# ssis endrowset not picking up last row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl

I'm running an SSIS job with a script transformation. This reads in a file, collects data in an array and outputs data from the array when there is a change in key. However, this does not appear to be processing the last record/array group as the EndofRowset does not seem to be executed. This is set up as an asynchronous script transformation. The code all works except for picking the last array group

Here is the condensed code..

```
Public Overrides Sub MyInput_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As MyInputBuffer)
    While Row.NextRow()
        Process_recs(Row.AOS, Row.Session, Row.AOSTitle, CInt(Row.ResourceHrs), CInt(Row.TotalTargetNo))
    End While
    If Row.EndOfRowset Then
        MsgBox("LAST RECORD " & CStr(QTUT_count))
        do_output_data(QTUT_count, strAOS, IntTargetplusHours, StrQTUT)
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub Process_recs(ByRef subAOS As String, ByRef subSession As String, ByRef subAOStitle As String, ByRef subResourceHrs As Integer, ByVal subTotalTargetNo As Integer)
       'code here collects data in an aray and sends to output on change  of key
        do_output_data(QTUT_count, strAOS, IntTargetplusHours, StrQTUT)

End Sub
Public Sub do_output_data(ByVal QT_count As Integer, ByVal aos() As String, ByVal hrs() As Integer, ByVal QTUT() As String)
    'data moved from array and output

                        .AddRow()
                        .Group = Trim(aos(k)) + StrSuffix
                        .SubGroup = Trim(aos(intindex))

End Sub

Public Overrides Sub CreateNewOutputRows()
End Sub
Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
End Sub
Public Overrides Sub PrimeOutput(ByVal Outputs As Integer, ByVal OutputIDs() As Integer, ByVal Buffers() As Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineBuffer)
    MyBase.PrimeOutput(Outputs, OutputIDs, Buffers)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`public override void InputRows_ProcessInputRow(InputRowsBuffer Row)`  will execute for each row. What is the purpose of using **while**, remove the while loop.*

**You can check last row using another method:**

1. In your package add a DataFlow Task used to count Rows from the Source File `DFT RowCount`
2. in `DFT RowCount` add a `Flat File Source` and a `RowCount` component
3. Store the RowCount in a Variable (ex: `User::FileRowCount`)
4. Connect `DFT RowCount` to the DatafLow task you are using
5. Add the Variable `User::FileRowCount` To Script `ReadOnlyVariables`
6. in The Script Use the Following Code:

   ```
   Dim intRowCount As Integer = 0
   Dim intCurrentRow As Integer = 0

   Public Overrides Sub PreExecute()
       MyBase.PreExecute()
       intRowCount = Variables.FileRowCount
   End Sub

   Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)
       intCurrentRow += 1


           Process_recs(Row.AOS, Row.Session, Row.AOSTitle, CInt(Row.ResourceHrs), CInt(Row.TotalTargetNo))

       If intCurrentRow = intRowCount Then
           MsgBox("LAST RECORD " & CStr(QTUT_count))
           do_output_data(QTUT_count, strAOS, IntTargetplusHours, StrQTUT)
       End If


   End Sub

   Public Sub Process_recs(ByRef subAOS As String, ByRef subSession As String, ByRef subAOStitle As String, ByRef subResourceHrs As Integer, ByVal subTotalTargetNo As Integer)
       'code here collects data in an aray and sends to output on change  of key
       do_output_data(QTUT_count, strAOS, IntTargetplusHours, StrQTUT)

   End Sub

   Public Sub do_output_data(ByVal QT_count As Integer, ByVal aos() As String, ByVal hrs() As Integer, ByVal QTUT() As String)
       'data moved from array and output

       .AddRow()
       .Group = Trim(aos(k)) + StrSuffix
       .SubGroup = Trim(aos(intindex))

   End Sub
   ```

Comment: Many thanks http://stackoverflow.com/users/7031230/hadi that solved my problem. Simple when you know how :-)

Comment: Very happy to help